# isinf is forbidden in submit to appstore

Tags: iphone, ipad

My application has been rejected because of `isinf`. What's an equivalent I can use to get my application accepted?

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

Did they specifically mention `isinf`? If so, it may be worth challenging the rejection as `isinf` and `isfinite` are both documented: [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/isinf.3.html) as part of the iOS API.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
if(!isfinite(var))
{
    //It's infinite...
}
```

Or you could try:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:myNumber];
if(number == [NSDecimalNumber notANumber])
{
    //Infinity??
}
```

Comment: I use isfinite and get rejected too